# Printing 2 lists in python

Tags: python

I’m trying to learn python and I was using an app.
In one of the tests it asked me for the output of:

```
list = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
print(list[list[4]])
```

I couldn’t find the solution and I looked at the solution, It was 8. But the problem is, it doesn’t show you why. I did a little search on this subject on google and stackoverflow but I couldn’t find why. Maybe I don’t know how to ask this question. Anyways, as I said I’m pretty new to this stuff so the title probably doesn’t fit the question but I really don’t know how to write my question in 5 words. It would be great if you help.

Comment: `list[4]` is `5`. `list[5]` is `8`. Therefore it will print out `8`.

Comment: Also, don't use the name `list` for variable names since it's a built-in python function. Instead use `list1`, for example

Comment: run it by your self. and see. For example you may run it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php)

Comment: You can put any expression into the `list[...]` part, as long as it produces something sensible to index with. `list[4]` uses `4` to index the list with. But `list[4]` is itself an expression that produces a value; in this case `5`, and that result is still a sensible value to pass to `list[...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work from the inside to the outside of these calls. That line is equivalent to the following:

```
value1 = list[4]   # this is 5 
value2 = list[value1]   # this is 8
print(value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the value of `List[List[4]]`

First, let's substitute the inner part `List[4]` 
and it will equal `5` as we count from `0` in python so you have:

```
list[0] = 1
list[1] = 1
list[2] = 2
list[3] = 3
list[4] = 5
```

and so on.

So now after getting the inner part we can easily figure out the overall question as follows:

```
 List[List[4]] = List[5] = 8
```